# angular - browser rendering performance using two ngFor loops

Tags: angular, performance, browser, ngfor, html-rendering

I'm building a timeline component with angular with a stepless zoom similar to this [example with vis-timeline](https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/examples/timeline/basicUsage.html) and I have some questions about rendering performance.

When you zoom in or out, there is a current scale for which steps are displayed depending on the width of the scale. E.g. 10 or 15 Minute steps for an hour scale. Please take into account that using the mousewheel, events are fired rapidly.

Please consider the two following options

1.

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items; trackBy:trackByItemId" style="display:flex" [style.width]="item.width" [style.transform]="item.translateX">
    <div *ngFor="let subItem of item.subItems; trackBy:trackBySubItemId" style="flex:1"></div>
</div>
```

2. 

```html
<div *ngFor="let subItem of item.subItems; trackBy:trackBySubItemId" [style.width]="subiItem.width" [style.transform]="subItem.translateX"></div>
```

The first option is a double ngFor loop where I use the css flex property to render the steps within a scale. The second option uses a single ngFor loop where only the steps are rendering.

Note that width and translateX are calculated in javascript and are for this example negligible.
Also note that *trackBy* is enabled, which keeps track of already created DOM Elements to improve performance.

I have two questions.

1. Does changing the width of a parent DOM element also triggers Paint, Layout and Composite for all child elements, as in case of option 1?
2. Which of the two options is efficient when only around 100-200 step elements will be displayed at any given time?